# Two [style.filter] binding on a single element in angular

Tags: angular, styles, css-filters

I have two slider on one div displaying an image, one for `blur` and the other for `hue-rotate`.

My html i have adapted following one answer:

```
<img src="{{ quizedMovie.poster}}" alt="movie poster" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 100%;" [ngStyle]="{'filter': blurring + ' ' + color }">

 <div class= "container">
Blur<mat-slider min="0" max="15" step="1" value="1"  (input)="onBlurChange($event)"></mat-slider>
Color<mat-slider min="0" max="360" step="10" value="1"  (input)="onColorChange($event)"></mat-slider>
 </div>
```

My ts:

```
  onBlurChange(event: any) {
    let blurValue= event.value   
    this.blurring = "blur("+ blurValue +"px)"
  }

  onColorChange(event: any) {
    let colorValue= event.value   
    this.color = "hue-rotate("+ colorValue +"deg)"
  }
```

Now the issue I am facing is that when the picture is loaded, in the Chrome Inspector Tool, my image has no style. If I change one of the two values with the slider, no style either.
But when I change both values, both style are applied. I tried to set a default value diferent that zero on both of them but the issue remains the same.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-jiwyrp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are missing to show us how you are binding the “this.blurring” and “this.color”.

<div [ngStyle]="{'filter': blurring + ' ' + color }"

You can also create a method to concatenate the strings this.blurring + this.color.
Double check in Chrome Inspector what is being applied in the DOM and in the Styles.

Comment: I've edited my question and tried your answer.